# How to pull changes from external repo that was merged into our own repo

Tags: git

I have merged one folder from external repo into my own repo. This was done by calling following commands:

```
git remote add -t master -f slidingmenu https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.git
git merge -s ours --no-commit --squash slidingmenu/master
git read-tree --prefix=SlidingMenu/ -u slidingmenu/master:library
git commit -m "Merge Project SlidingMenu into SlidingMenu folder"
```

As you can see, I have merged only the "library" subfolder of the slidingmenu repo, and put it to SlidingMenu folder in my repo.
Is there now a simple way to pull updates from external repo into my own?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do a normal merge now  - it will see the changes you have in your repo, and will only merge what needs to be merged.